# How can I refresh the pager after updating the data for a kendo grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a table that I want to refresh with new product data when a checkbox is selected. I'm attempting to do this by creating a template and applying that to each row in the table. The problem that I'm having is after the table is refreshed with the new data the pagination for that table doesn't update. By this I mean that it still shows that it has the same number of rows it had before updating the table. I've condensed the products object just to keep it simple. My code is below:

```
var template = kendo.template
(
    "<td>#: id #</td>" +
    "<td>#: name #</td>" +
    "<td>#: dateCreated #</td>
);

var products = [
    { id: 1, name: "product1", dateCreated: "01/15/2019" },
    { id: 2, name: "product2", dateCreated: "03/02/2019" },
    { id: 3, name: "product3", dateCreated: "11/22/2018" }
];

$(".grid:eq(1)").html(template(products));
$(".grid:eq(1)").data("kendoPager").refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax binding.  It should automatically pull data from a Db table and update whenever new data is added on the client side.  If your check box is just to specify it to update you would not even need to include that.  If you are trying to automatically update from the server side you are going to need to just have it refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Kevin. The table will only be updated if the user clicks on a checkbox. If I'm receiving the data from an Ajax response would the call to "refresh" solve the pagination issue?

Comment: As far as I know yes.  The Ajax works by calling a Post method that reads in from the database.  If you set the checkbox to call that Post method it should refresh the table.  Obv you would need to have the Post method check which checkbox was checked to appropriately pull the correct data but it should work.  You also have to consider if you are pulling the data from client side or server side.